# helloWorld.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized (cross-assembling a Linux executable on Windows)

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, cross-compiling

I assembled an assembly file called "helloWorld.s" and saved it into "helloWorld.o" and then I tried to link it but it gave me this error "helloWorld.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized", I wonder why is that?

I used NASM Assembler.

Here are the commands I wrote:

```
C:\>nasm -f elf64 helloWorld.s

C:\>ld -o helloWorld helloWorld.o
helloWorld.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

Note:

The Executable for linux OS but I just trying to essemble it and link it on Windows OS and the will transfer it.

Comment: Likely because your linker only supports Windows PE(+) objects and helloworld.o is ELF. What happens if you pass `-f win64` to NASM instead of `-f elf64`?

Comment: If you're following a tutorial that told you to build with `nasm -felf64`, the code probably uses Linux system-call numbers, which won't work on Windows even if you do assemble + link that code into a Windows executable.

Comment: The executable indeed for linux OS i'm just trying to asemble it and linke it on windows machine and then transfer it. @PeterCordes

Comment: Then use an x86-64 ELF linker, not whatever that `ld` is.  `ld --help` or `ld --version` might tell you what you have.  (If it's GNU Binutils `ld`, it could perhaps be configured for 32-bit only?  Or with 32-bit as the default, so `ld -m elf_x86_64` might work.)

Comment: Or try using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Linux executable on Windows using the ld linker is not a straightforward process because ld on Windows typically produces Windows-compatible executables (PE format), not Linux-compatible executables (ELF format). However, you can use a cross-compiler toolchain on Windows to achieve your goal.